# On back press go back to previous view

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity in which i have 3 views.On click of a button i have hidden one view and displayed other one.But my doubt is that i cannot go back to the previous view.How should i do this.

For eg:`I am on view A, and i click a button so now view A is hidden and now B is displayed.Now if press back button A should be displayed again but this is not happening,y app is directly closing.`

Code

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.bt_continue_1:
        if (str_first_name.equals("") || str_last_name.equals("") || str_gender.equals("Select Gender") || str_religion.equals("Select Religion") || str_age.equals("Select Age")) {
              commonFunctions.showAlert(this, "INVALID", "Please fill all the mandatory details");
              personal_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
              professional_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              contact_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        } else {
              header.setText("Contact Info");
              personal_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateLeft());
              contact_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateRight());
              personal_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              professional_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              contact_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.bt_continue_2:
        if (str_mobile.equals("") || str_state.equals("Select State") || strCity.equals("") || str_area.equals("") || str_address.equals("")) {
              commonFunctions.showAlert(this, "INVALID", "Please fill all the mandatory details");
              personal_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              professional_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              contact_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        } else {
              header.setText("Professional Info");
              contact_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateLeft());
              professional_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateRight());
              personal_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              contact_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
              professional_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        }
        break;
//
//            if( code== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
//
//            }

    case R.id.bt_save:
//                AddUpdateJobResource async = new AddUpdateJobResource (personal_info.this, "0", "34588A34-E969-4723-84FE-E5409B66A5B7", "", str_first_name, str_last_name, gender_id, age_substring, nationality_id, "IND", "INDIA", state_code, str_state, str_city, str_area, str_address, str_mobile, profession_id, religion_id, "2", months_substring, yrs_substring, "0.00", "0.00", "hssuraksha");
//                async.execute ();
        AddResources addResources = new AddResources();
        addResources.execute();
    }
}
```

Please do suggest something

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem exactly. Do you mean the back button of the device or the a custom designed button in your application? In the latter case you can simply call the finish()-Method of your Activity when the button is pressed.

```
 case R.id.bt_back:
      // finish current view and go back to last view
      finish();
```

Comment: he is trying to use Back button in order to change between the views because he is using view hierarchy alteration rather than Fragments

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to make view A and view B into fragments instead of hiding/showing their specific data. If you still want to use your paradigm you could override the onBackPressed to show view A when it is pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("YOUR_APP", "onBackPressed Called");  
   //Show/Hide stuff here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The back button works on activities, not on views.

The default back logic is (well, more or less) 'close current activity and return to
the one before'.

if you want to override this behavior add code like below to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (v1.getVisibility() == view.VISIBLE) {
       // hide v1, show v2, v3
       v1.setVisibility(view.GONE);
       v2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
       v3.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
   }
   else if (v2.getVisibility() == view.VISIBLE) {
       // hide v2, show v1, v3
       v2.setVisibility(view.GONE);
       v1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
       v3.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
   }
   else if (v2.getVisibility() == view.VISIBLE) {
       // close activity
       finish();
   }
}
```

or whatever other back-button logic your application requires.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to navigate from activity 3 to activity 1? Dependend on your use case you could override the standard task and backstack behavior. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html